# Automatic Open Graph Post creating multiple posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created custom action and custom object types.

I create custom object instance using [Facebook Open Graph Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/)

I get the id of the object and use the id to post the story.

In the timeline, I see 2 posts:

1. "User" posted "custom object title" via "app name"
2. Story that I explicitly published.

Why is (1) getting created? Is it possible to avoid (1) in some manner?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) is posted if the object is being created using the user access token.

When the app access token is used, then (1) is not published.

Of course, you should not use the app access token on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How Open Graph Works](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview/). They are tied up  to an action and that is why (1) is created.  If you only want to publish the story, I would suggest using a "status update" on Facebook.  Also, take a look at [Parse](https://www.parse.com/products/social). Facebook recently bought it and it's super easy to integrate.